# Toast from spinner not showing

Tags: android, spinner, android-toast

The spinner has an array list of band genres when selecting any of the genres in the spinner it will display a toast, the toast isn't showing when clicking the spinner, the code isn't showing any errors ? any ideas why ?

```
    String spinnerSelection = null;
    Spinner spinner = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );



       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerContent);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                                                                         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        {

            Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(),"Hell Yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
}
```

Comment: use MainActivity.this as context in toast

Comment: Problem is your `onItemSelected` does not getting called as you haven't set `onItemSelectedListener` to you spinner

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add click listener in the spinner

```
    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding setOnClickListener() on your button. Add setOnItemClickListener() to your spinner.

Comment: the button leads to the other activity pages

Comment: Ok then add spinner.setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: Yes. Below those two lines, add the following lines:

 spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(),"Show your Devil Horns !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: Yes delete it and if it is still not working, post the stack trace here. And write getApplicationContext() instead of getBasecontext() in Toast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `@Override` for `onItemSelected(...)` and `onNothingSelected(...)` functions.

Make sure you set a listener on the spinner:
`spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Edit

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    MediaPlayer myMusic;
    int paused;


    public void play(View view) {
        if (myMusic == null) {
            myMusic = MediaPlayer.create( this, R.raw.fast_and_cold );
            myMusic.start();


        }
    }


    public void stop(View view) {
        myMusic.reset();
        myMusic = null;
    }



    String spinnerSelection = null;
    Spinner spinner = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );



        final List<String> spinnerContent = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerContent.add("Black Metal");
        spinnerContent.add("Death Metal");
        spinnerContent.add("Thrash Metal");
        spinnerContent.add("Heavy Metal");



        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerContent);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); // add this line



        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {





    }

    @Override // add this line
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position, long id) {


            Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(),"Show your Devil Horns !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override // add this line
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    } 

}
```

Comment: could you highlight which part ? this is fist time making an app

Comment: @redhotrocketsss see my edited. Checkout `// add this line` comments. Three of them